# How to install new Laravel project

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

I need to create a new Laravel project on Windows using composer but when I run this command: `laravel new blood` it gives me this error on composer:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
  TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.


new [--dev] [--] <name>
```

I never faced that error and it already creates a new project but the project doesn't run on the browser as it gives me a problem in the `autoload.php`.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
composer global require "laravel/installer":"1.3.1"
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```